# Can theory exposition be a thesis?

Tags: thesis, undergraduate

I'm an undergraduate student majoring in math, and ,as my graduation condition requires, I'm planning to write a thesis, but will it be okay to just write an exposition of the theory?

Comment: What is the alternative?  Original research?  The only way to get a definitive answer is to ask your advisor or others in your department, but I'm confident that an expository undergraduate thesis would be fine.

Comment: I have no idea what "theory-expository" means.

Comment: As an undergraduate, it will be rare that you are able to do more than exposition at all anyway (as "more" would move into doing actual research).

Comment: @JeffE For example, explaining some basic theory, call it abstract algebra, and then introducing its applications to galois theory or algebraic topology...

Comment: Only your faculty advisor can answer this question.  Expectations for undergraduate (and graduate!) theses vary dramatically from one department to the next.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For undergraduate studies, you do not need to have publishable papers. Hence, exploratory thesis it is fine if you understand and do all the calculations, and perhaps you can also explore implementations in numerical programs.

Comment: Just a reminder: unless @MikeyMike is actually faculty/staff at your department, he is just a random internet dude. Ask your advisor (or someone equivalent!)